# how to set any post creation for pending status and let the admin approve it first?

Tags: user-roles

how to set any post creation to PENDING status and the admin should approve it to make it available to be displayed on the site ?

Answer (score 1):

> if your website has users granted the edit_posts capability but not
>   the publish_posts capability, then when those users start writing a
>   new post, WordPress will display a "Submit for Review" button instead
>   of a "Publish" button. Likewise, WordPress then assigns the post that
>   user created the pending status when they press that button.

This is from WordPress Codex - https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status

Comment: Unfortunately i made those changed in the user capabilities but unfortunately still any post created from the contributor role goes into publish status automatically :(

Comment: add users as "contributor" and it will give you this functonality

Comment: am using the plugin called 'User Front End' when we create the post using the new registered user it goes directly to publish not pending

Comment: there is an option of setting post status under "post setting". Change it to pending review.

Comment: its already changed to pending review but it didn't effect